# RedisTemplate nullException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

There was a problem when I used Springboot to integrate Redis. I want to customize a RedisTemplate, and when I use it, I find that it is always empty and cannot be injected. My code is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean(name = "myRedisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);

        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);
        StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        template.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
```

```
   @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "myRedisTemplate")
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
```

**redisTemplate is empty in debug mode.I don't know what went wrong**

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by `jedisConnectionFactory` do you have such a **Bean**

```
@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}
```